# How to change the default animation duration for UINavigation View ios?

Tags: ios

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
 [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];
```

I know about default animation duration , but i want to know about how to change the animation duration.

My actual code was below

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
 [navController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];
 [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
 [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

how we can add animation for above code

Comment: You mean the sliding animation when you set, push or pop view controllers?

Comment: pop view controller with view coming from bottom side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Documentation:**

```
  setViewControllers: animated:
```

> If animations are enabled, this method decides which type of transition to perform based on whether the last item in the items array is already in the navigation stack. Only one transition is performed, but when that transition finishes,
>   the entire contents of the stack are replaced with the new view
>   controllers.

There is no native method to call the animate with duration in this case.

You can try adding the **CATransition** to the navigation controller layer, and you can change the duration of the transiton as you like.

You can subclass the navigation controller and do something like:

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];
```

You can find different sets of animation [here:](http://www.davidhamrick.com/2011/12/31/Changing-the-UINavigationController-animation-style.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Here is my answer .*

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
                [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

                [UIView setAnimationTransition:
                 UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                                       forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];


                [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:NO];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];

                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

**according to Mr.T answer**

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                transition.duration = 0.3f;
                transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
                transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
                [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
                [self.navigationController setViewControllers: @[rootViewController] animated: YES];
                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];

                [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```